# ¿Cómo se le llama a un grupo de flechas disparadas?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

Todos hemos visto en documentales históricos o en ficciones cómo un grupo de arqueros se adelanta, dispara simultáneamente una ráfaga de flechas hacia el enemigo y se retira (o pone otra flecha en el arco, etc.). ¿Hay algún término para esta lluvia o ráfaga de flechas disparadas coordinadamente? En inglés se dice *volley of arrows*; en castellano se me ocurrió que debía ser una *andanada*, pero según la RAE una [andanada](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=andanada) se refiere a cañones. ¿Será posible extender este término a las flechas, o hay otro más específico?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63603/discussion-on-question-by-pablodf76-como-se-le-llama-a-un-grupo-de-flechas-disp). Si tenéis alguna sugerencia, publicadla como respuesta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hice una búsqueda y me di cuenta que esta terminología está muy presente en los videojuegos de batallas. Veo referenciadas la [**descarga de flechas**](http://www.guildwiki.es/wiki/Descarga_de_flechas), así como [**lluvia de flechas**](http://wiki.metin2.es/index.php/Lluvia_de_Flechas).

Siguiendo cona la investigación, di con un artículo de la Wikipedia llamado *Tácticas romanas de infantería*. En la sección [Problemas tácticos al luchar contra la caballería](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A1cticas_romanas_de_infanter%C3%ADa#Problemas_t.C3.A1cticos_al_luchar_contra_la_caballer.C3.ADa) observo el uso de **enjambre de flechas** para referirse al cúmulo de flechas lanzadas por uno de los contendientes. He aquí los fragmentos:

> Ambos tipos de tropas utilizaron poderosos arcos compuestos que lanzaban flechas con la potencia suficiente para perforar las armaduras romanas. Los catafractos servían entonces como tropas de choque, que cargaban con la fuerza de un ariete contra las filas romanas, una vez se habían "ablandado" tras los *enjambres de flechas*.

y luego

> Cuadrado Hueco. Esta táctica proveía una defensa en todas direcciones, dejando un pivote para comenzar la ofensiva. En el cuadro, las tropas podían parapetarse contra los *enjambres de flechas* utilizando sus grandes escudos.

Tiene su sentido, pues es muy gráfico y esta palabra ya saltó del ámbito de las abejas a algo más genérico:

> [**enjambre**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FSGY3tm)
>   Del lat. exāmen, -ĭnis.
>   1. m. Multitud de abejas con su maestra, que juntas salen de una colmena para formar otra colonia.
>   2. m. Muchedumbre de personas o animales juntos.

Sin embargo, una búsqueda de "enjambre de flechas" no arroja demasiados resultados y, como indica walen en los comentarios, parece una licencia del editor de la Wikipedia al traducir la [*Anábasis* de Jenofonte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1basis_de_Jenofonte) (véase la [revisión exacta donde lo introdujo](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=T%C3%A1cticas_romanas_de_infanter%C3%ADa&oldid=17929737)).

Comment: Como nota por quien recibe la lluvia de flechas: No lo he encontrado para un grupo de personas, o tropa, pero si algo / alguien muere de recibir varias flechas se puede decir que murió asaetado, del verbo asaetear (‘Disparar saetas [contra alguien o algo]’). Tres armenios habían asaetado un león // El mantra familiar poco le sirve ahora a Tywin, que es asaetado hasta morir // Aun así, a mi lado cayó desplomado Lope tras ser asaetado.

Comment: Y tampoco encontré las tropas asaetan a los enemigos, parece que es cuando él que dispara **o** él que recibe es 'alguien' o 'algo', pero no 'algunos'.

Answer (score 7):

Tanto *lluvia de flechas*, ya mencionada por OP, como las expresión *enjambre de flechas* [propuesta por fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21749/13628) transmiten bien el concepto, y de hecho son bastante usadas (sobre todo la primera); pero en mi opinión es más por metáfora que por tener *lluvia* o *enjambre* ese significado específico.

Por mi parte voy a proponer "salva de flechas":

> **[salva](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=X7mZ3Mp)**
>   4. f. Disparo simultáneo de varias piezas idénticas de artillería o de fusilería.

En este caso, el significado intrínseco de la palabra sí está relacionado con el tema. Igual que se habla de salvas de fusil o salvas de cañón, podríamos decir salvas de arco o, por extensión, salvas de flechas.

Puede argumentarse que, cuando aún no existían las armas de fuego, los arqueros eran el equivalente a la artillería actual: un cuerpo de batalla encargado de lanzar proyectiles a las tropas enemigas para diezmarlas y facilitar el trabajo de infantería y caballería.
Más aún si consideramos [armas de asedio como la balista](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balista), que viene a ser una ballesta del tamaño de un camión. ¡Pocas cosas se me ocurren más parecidas a un cañón actual!

En este sentido, cientos de arcos o ballestas siendo disparados al mismo tiempo producirían una salva, y el enemigo recibiría dicha salva:

> *A menos de una legua, los arqueros enemigos comenzaron a disparar. Recibimos la primera salva de flechas parapetados tras nuestros escudos. Y luego la segunda. Y la tercera. Para cuando empezó a temblar el suelo bajo los cascos de la caballería acercándose a rematarnos, solo unos pocos seguíamos en pie.*

Comment: Me gusta. Deberías poner la fuente del último párrafo citado.

Answer (score 6):

Según el DLE, [*flechería*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I4RGRXG) designa, efectivamente, al "conjunto de flechas disparadas" (así como *[fusilería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IeGrnbT)* se refiere al fuego de fusiles).

El término parece poco usado en la actualidad (los ejemplos que encontré son del Siglo de Oro) y es más común leer *lluvia, nube, enjambre* (o similar) *de flechas*.

Tampoco implica este término (ni ningún otro, me parece, por lo que veo) que el conjunto de flechas sea producto de una táctica coordinada u organizada, por más que se pueda suponer que lanzar muchas flechas requiera un mínimo de organización, así que eso debería surgir del contexto en que se utilice.

Comment: Por [definición](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I4RGRXG), esta es la respuesta. :-)

Comment: [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flecher%C3%ADa%2Clluvia+de+flechas&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflecher%C3%ADa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clluvia%20de%20flechas%3B%2Cc0) muestra que aunque superior, **lluvia de flechas** no es _muuucho_ más usado que **flechería**. (aunque siempre he tenido reservas sobre el uso de ngram)

Comment: Please see Meta question about your recent edit: See related Meta question: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2821/9385