# ¿Cómo se ordenaba disparar antes de que existieran las armas de fuego?

Tags: historia, español-medieval

Hoy, reviendo la peli *“El Señor de los Anillos II: Las dos torres”* junto con mi esposa, ella observó que cuando el rey de Rohan ordena comenzar a disparar contra los orcos, el mismo grita en el original *“Fire!”*, es decir, “¡Fuego!”, que por otra parte es lo que hubiera gritado en español, supongo. Sin embargo, en este caso se trataba de disparar flechas, y no existen las armas de fuego, que son las que hoy justifican el uso de la exclamación antedicha y de la expresión “hacer fuego” por “disparar, arrojar”. ¿Sabemos cuál es la palabra o expresión que se utilizaba para esto en español antes de la invención de las armas de fuego? Por caso, ¿sabemos desde cuándo se dice “¡Fuego!” en español? (En inglés antiguo, por lo que rápidamente pude chequear, debía usarse el verbo que corresponde a *shoot* o un derivado suyo.)

P.S.: Alguien ya hizo [esta pregunta](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158711/fire-a-weapon-before-firearms-existed) en English.SE, con varias respuestas, y me interesa un punto tangencial: las [andanadas de flechas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21721/c%C3%B3mo-se-le-llama-a-un-grupo-de-flechas-disparadas) son un concepto bastante abusado en Hollywood pero generalmente irreal; nadie dobla un arco y se queda esperando a que le den la orden de disparar sincronizadamente con otros, porque mantener el arco doblado requiere un esfuerzo considerable y es dañino para el arco mismo.

Comment: Muy interesante. Yo habría pensado que en inglés usarían "release" si tienes a un grupo de arqueros y quieres que todos disparen las flechas al tiempo. Si tengo tiempo buscaré fragmentos de Braveheart, Gladiator o alguna similar a ver si encuentro alguna batalla en la que se ordene disparar a grupos de arqueros. Es español no sé que verbo se usaría. Por cierto que esta (gran y muy interesante) pregunta, en su variante sobre el inglés, lo mismo te compensa hacerla al mismo tiempo en alguno de los stacks hermanos dedicados a la lengua inglesa.

Comment: En el CORDE veo algún caso de "dispararon las flechas" en textos del siglo XVI, pero no veo el uso del verbo como orden. Hay que tener en cuenta también que el uso del cañón en España está documentado [desde el siglo XIII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%B1%C3%B3n_medieval): "El primer documento conocido databa de 1249 (El Escorial), en 1247 en la defensa de Sevilla se hablan de 'cañones arrojando piedras' y en 1259 lo mismo, en Melilla."

Comment: Según este artículo para inglés (porque Tolkien escribió en inglés) [In movies archers are always given the order to "Fire", is this an accurate command?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/10ze0u/in_movies_archers_are_always_given_the_order_to/)  Las palabras ingles son: Ready! Nock! Mark! Draw! Loose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verbo *disparar* no es tampoco demasiado antiguo, aparece en diccionarios a partir del siglo XVI, y tiene la siguiente entrada en el *Covarruvias* de 1611:

> DISPARAR, vale desbaratar, y disparar la ballesta, es despedir della el virote, o la saeta.

Más antiguo que este es el verbo *tirar*, usado ya en siglo XIII:

> *[...] e los vnos de aquestos tirauan de arco e los otros de ballesta [...].*
>
> ---
>
> *E muchos ouo y a quien peso de la su cayda, se quiera luego a Paris que puso vna saeta en su arco e tirola contra el duc e feriolo por el costado.*
>
> Anónimo, "Historia troyana en prosa y verso", c 1270 (España).

Otro de la época:

> *Este Lamec fue omne que tirava de arco muy bien, e acertava mucho e matava muchos venados [...].*
>
> Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Primera parte", c 1275 (España).

Este verbo se usaba entonces igual que se se sigue usando hoy ("tiro con arco", "tiro con ballesta"), aunque con otra preposición. A la vista de esto se podría pensar en usar este verbo para dar la orden ("¡tirad!"), el caso más claro que he encontrado de este verbo usado en imperativo es también el más antiguo:

> *Dixo Heliseus: "Prent el arco e las saetas e tira con el".*
>
> Almerich, "La fazienda de Ultra Mar", c 1200 (España).

No es una orden dada a un grupo en plan *¡fuego!*, pero orden al fin y al cabo.

Answer (score 1):

"Suelten".  Lo mismo que usan en "Juego de Tronos".